# Combining previously different rows after changing value during query

Tags: t-sql, group-by, case, substring

I'm currently running a query that is supposed to return a salesperson's aggregated revenue, grouped by individual clients.

Because of how user input was handled, there are a lot of near-duplicate rows with minor mispellings/additions to client names. As you can see in the code below, I'm trying to trim off one of the problem strings in order to prevent duplicate rows for the same clients.

However, though the CASE statement successfully removes "@iraPrefix", the rows with now-identical client names are still not grouped together because their revenue fields are not being summed.

How should I approach this?

```
DECLARE @iraPrefix VARCHAR(7)
DECLARE @iraLen INT
SET @iraPrefix = 'FOO BAR '
SET @iraLen = LEN(@iraPrefix)

SELECT [client] = (
           CASE SUBSTRING([name], 1, @iraLen)
               WHEN @iraPrefix THEN SUBSTRING([name], @iraLen+2, (LEN([name]) - @iraLen))
               ELSE [name]
           END
       )
       , CONCAT( sal.firstname
               , ' '
               , sal.lastname) AS [salesman]
       , [revenue] = SUM(net)
```

Here's an example of the query results without prefix removal:

[image]

An example of the current query results:

[image]

And an example of the results I want:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the network :) Good effort on your first post. To make it even better in the future, have a look at [repro] & keep in mind that text is almost always preferred of images when possible. My go-to utility for ASCII-text tables is http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables

Answer (score 0):

Just aggregate one more time.

You can do this by

- Materialising your intermediate resultset ([`SELECT ... INTO #intermediate FROM...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql)) and then aggregating the cached intermediate results
- Wrapping your current query in a set of brackets and `SELECT`ing against whatever alias you assign to it.

See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dd5fa7c659727406277046ac4c81fcbc) for an example. But for verbosity's sake, assuming your data is all stored in a table called `barfoo`, then one way you could do this using a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) (or CTE) is...

```sql
DECLARE @iraPrefix VARCHAR(7);
DECLARE @iraLen INT;
SET @iraPrefix = 'FOO BAR ';
SET @iraLen = LEN(@iraPrefix);

WITH L1 AS (
   SELECT [client] = (
           CASE SUBSTRING([name], 1, @iraLen)
               WHEN @iraPrefix THEN SUBSTRING([name], @iraLen+2, (LEN([name]) - @iraLen))
               ELSE [name]
           END
       )
       , CONCAT( sal.firstname
               , ' '
               , sal.lastname) AS [salesman]
       , [revenue] = SUM(net)
   FROM barfoo as sal
   GROUP BY [name],CONCAT( sal.firstname
                      , ' '
                      , sal.lastname) 
)
SELECT 
        [client],
        [salesman],
        SUM([revenue]) AS [revenue]
FROM L1
GROUP BY [client],
        [salesman];
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to separate the cleaning and aggregation steps using CTEs. This makes each obvious to comprehend, change and debug. Something like

```
; with Clean as
(

    SELECT [client] = (
               CASE SUBSTRING([name], 1, @iraLen)
                   WHEN @iraPrefix THEN SUBSTRING([name], @iraLen+2, (LEN([name]) - @iraLen))
                   ELSE [name]
               END
           )
           , CONCAT( sal.firstname
                   , ' '
                   , sal.lastname) AS [salesman]
           , net
)
select
    client
   ,salesman
   ,[revenue] = SUM(net)
from Clean
group by client, salesman;
```

There is no guarantee that at run-time the CTE will be executed first and then the aggregation. The optimizer may re-arrange the bits however is chooses for best performance. What it comes up with *is* guaranteed to implement the query you provide, though. This leaves us, the developers, to arrange the query however we choose for optimal human comprehension, in this case using a CTE. (There can be exceptional circumstances where the optimizer gives a poorly-performing plan and the best solution is to re-arrange the SQL; this will not be one of those circumstances.)